# Meaning of various meta tags

Tags: html, meta

I want to know the what the following meta tags mean and do:

- `<meta name="revised" content="Alpha, 9/18/2013" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: Can you added a bit more description for your meta tags. It will be more useful down the road to a reader if you had a bit better explanation or question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
```

Is used to make browser refresh the page after 30 seconds

```
<meta name="revised" content="Alpha, 9/18/2013" />
```

The revised meta tag records when the last update was done to the site

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

is used to define the character set for an HTML document

Comment: Ok, thanks. This was an appropriate answer of my Question. This thing was whirling my mind since for a long time. Thanks to Stack Overflow and Special thanks to you

Comment: Should a person keep track of when a page was revised? Where does it store this data?

Comment: @DougHauf if you are asking me about revised meta tag then its not for a person but for search engines. It just makes search engines change their index and its upto the search engine.