# How would I get an alarm using sessions when variable change?

Tags: php, session

Im trying to build a single page that gets content using "file_get_contents" function, I have managed this part. The content ends up in a variable called $content. The idea is to get an alert (by sound) when the content changes.

What I have faild at is the part where I compare the old value for $content with the new one. Somehow I must keep the old value and compare it with the new one and **when I reload the page** I would like to get an alert **if $content has changed**. I was thinking I should use sessions for this comparison.
This is what I got:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['red'] = $red;
if($red != $content) {echo "ALERT" . $content = $_SESSION['red'];}
if($red == $content) {echo "Same";}
```

It is not working, probably looks like crap since I have no clue what im doing really :)

Below is the code for setting the $content variable:

```
$page = file_get_contents('data.htm');
if ( preg_match ( '/<a tabindex="50" class="item_link".*?a>/s', $page, $matches ) )
{
    foreach ( $matches as $key => $content )
    {
        echo $key . ' => ' .  $content  . '<br /><br />';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'No match';
}
?>
```

For the Alert sound I found a script;

```
<script>
  var audio = document.createElement('audio');
 document.body.appendChild(audio);
  audio.src = 'http://rpg.hamsterrepublic.com/wiki-images/2/21/Collision8-Bit.ogg';
  setInterval(function(){audio.play();}, 5000);
 </script>
```

Need help activating this script if the $content has changed, also to make it only play once.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about having no clue what somebody is doing really. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commend your self-efacing attitude.:)

One problem, I think, is the way you've written your if statement(s):

if($red != $content) {echo "ALERT" . $content = $_SESSION['red'];}
if($red == $content) {echo "Same";}

Firstly, the '.' after echo "ALERT" should, I think be a ';'.
Secondly, use an else rather than the 2 if statements. Why write more code than you need to and (more importantly) the assignment in your first if makes your second if true!!

Also, I think you want to be making $red = $_SESSION['red'] at the start, then make $_SESSION['red'] = $content.

Finally, use strcmp() instead of == or !=  (strcmp() is more reliable for comparing strings  - remember it returns false when the strings match though).

So, you end up with:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$red=(array_key_exists('red',$_SESSION)?$_SESSION['red']:'');

... set up $content

if(strcmp("$red","$content") )
{ // what you've previously read doesn't match the new content
  echo "ALERT";
  // escape back to the html to do the sound stuff
?>
<script>
  var audio = document.createElement('audio');
 document.body.appendChild(audio);
  audio.src = 'http://rpg.hamsterrepublic.com/wiki-images/2/21/Collision8-Bit.ogg';
  setInterval(function(){audio.play();}, 5000);
 </script>
<?php
  $_SESSION['red'] = $content; 
  // so now they both match the new content 
  // - so will give "same" next time round
} else {
  echo "Same";
}
...
```

Try this out.

Comment: Thank you very much! I dont know exactly how but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must consider that to re-run your PHP code, your page needs to refresh.
To achieve this, you may use the classic [html refresh through meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473853/meaning-of-various-meta-tags/12473945#12473945) (I suppose you want just *get things done*, otherwise you need some tutorials to understand better what you are doing).

Second, you can store the content of `data.htm` in a file on the server (it's not clever how data.htm is supposed to change, I imagine through FTP or something similar, if it should change through browser, notice that it's a **completely different story** and you have to follow some tutorials).

After you have done this, you can just compare `file_get_contents` result with the stored file and check if they are not the same. If they are not, print out your javascript code to have your page ring and replace the content of the file with the new fetched contents (otherwise will keep ringing).

No sessions in this way.